# Xcode 10.1 Running XCUITest and/or XCTest - Timed out waiting for target to check in

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I am running Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.14.4 (Mojave) and is unable to run any form of Test (XCUITest/XCTest) on my simulator. I constantly receive these error messages after the simulator is launched:

> Assertion Failure: :0: Failure requesting automation session for [My-APP-Bundle-Identifier]:3964: Timed out waiting for
>   target to check in.

Tried creating a fresh new project and run Test, this error message also occurs.

Debugger Log Output:

> - thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP   * frame #0: 0x00000001062fb22a
>     libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001062fb76c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 60
>     frame #2: 0x00000001039a11b4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
>     frame #3: 0x000000010399b7e9 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1689
>     frame #4: 0x000000010399ae11 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
>     frame #5: 0x000000010a9dc1dd GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
>     frame #6: 0x000000010e6ab81d UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 140
>     frame #7: 0x000000010061f924 KeyMap-DEV`main at AppDelegate.swift:21
>     frame #8: 0x0000000105fd7575 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>     frame #9: 0x0000000105fd7575 libdyld.dylib`start + 1   thread #5, name = 'com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread'
>     frame #0: 0x00000001062fb22a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001062fb76c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 60
>     frame #2: 0x00000001039a11b4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
>     frame #3: 0x000000010399b7e9 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1689
>     frame #4: 0x000000010399ae11 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
>     frame #5: 0x0000000102a5e322 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
>     frame #6: 0x0000000102a5e4f4 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 79
>     frame #7: 0x000000010e7a2bcb UIKitCore`-[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 118
>     frame #8: 0x0000000102a73732 Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 1221
>     frame #9: 0x00000001063522eb libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
>     frame #10: 0x0000000106355249 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 66
>     frame #11: 0x000000010635140d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13   thread #7, name = 'GAIThread'
>     frame #0: 0x00000001062fb22a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
>     frame #1: 0x00000001062fb76c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 60
>     frame #2: 0x00000001039a11b4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
>     frame #3: 0x000000010399b7e9 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1689
>     frame #4: 0x000000010399ae11 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
>     frame #5: 0x0000000102a5e322 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
>     frame #6: 0x0000000102a5e492 Foundation`-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
>     frame #7: 0x0000000100674a98 KeyMap-DEV`+[GAI threadMain:] + 62
>     frame #8: 0x0000000102a73732 Foundation`__NSThread__start__ + 1221
>     frame #9: 0x00000001063522eb libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 126
>     frame #10: 0x0000000106355249 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 66
>     frame #11: 0x000000010635140d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13   thread #13
>     frame #0: 0x00000001062fcbfe libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
>     frame #1: 0x0000000106351636 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 458
>     frame #2: 0x00000001063513fd libsystem_pthread.dylib`start_wqthread + 13

Anyone is experiencing this and found a resolution? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code of some of your tests? Preferably with setUp and tearDown methods. Also - do you run your tests from XCode or from terminal with xcbuild?

Comment: @Václav just setting up a new project, and run test also causes this issue. No code required I believed. I tried both and both failed by timing out.

Comment: This looks like your app is not launching properly. Do you have `super.setUp()` and `app.launch()` in your setUp block?

Comment: any workaround for this issue?